# How to hide GIF and replace with image (in order to use magnifying tool)

Tags: javascript, html, css, gif, squarespace

Hello stackoverflow world,

first post, complete noob here! I am trying to get with the times and look into some **webdesign** since this internet thing apparently is here to stay.

Could someone tell me a way to **hide a GIF** (already made it 1-loop only) **and replace it** with an image so I can use the magnifying-tool snippet I found on here.

```js
function magnify(imgID, zoom) {
  var img, glass, w, h, bw;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  /*create magnifier glass:*/
  glass = document.createElement("DIV");
  glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");
  /*insert magnifier glass:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
  /*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
  glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
  bw = 3;
  w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
  h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;
  /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
  glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  function moveMagnifier(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    x = pos.x;
    y = pos.y;
    /*prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {x = img.width - (w / zoom);}
    if (x < w / zoom) {x = w / zoom;}
    if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {y = img.height - (h / zoom);}
    if (y < h / zoom) {y = h / zoom;}
    /*set the position of the magnifier glass:*/
    glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
    glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
    /*display what the magnifier glass "sees":*/
    glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}
</script>

<script>
/* Initiate Magnify Function
with the id of the image, and the strength of the magnifier glass:*/
magnify("export-a-product-to-china", 2);
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.img-magnifier-container {
  position:relative;
}

.img-magnifier-glass {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: none;
  /*Set the size of the magnifier glass:*/
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-magnifier-container">
  <img id="export-a-product-to-china" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a27e60318b27d7d0e86bd68/t/5fda32c7b424be58e1607b44/1608135367867/anipro_bw_final.svg" width="960" height="540">
</div>
```

Thanks very much in advance!

**Edit:** The following answer by A Haworth solves the problem impeccably and with elegance (as far it is comprehensible for me and limited coding knowledge).
Thanks to him and others like him on this incredible site!

True camaraderie in the pursuit of knowledge is among the most noble treats of humanity. I honestly did not dare to hope this exited anymore.

Cheers to a new year in which I hope to grow into positions, that allow me to help others as I was helped.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet in the question does not work because the JS is in the wrong order, but if we alter it then it appears to work - ie one can move the magnifying glass over the image and see parts enlarged.

UPDATE: the requirement for overlaying a GIF on load was clarified in comments. This snippet therefore does two extra things: uses a pseudo element (:after) on the container to overlay the GIF using CSS animation timing to keep it there for 33 seconds (this can of course be changed); senses if the mouse has moved over a part of the window which is not the main image and if so sets the glass display to none.

```js
function magnify(imgID, zoom) {
  var img, glass, w, h, bw;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  img.parentElement.style.width = img.width + 'px';//ADDED so that the pseudo element can pick up the right dimensions
  img.parentElement.style.height = img.height + 'px';// - ditto - 
  /*create magnifier glass:*/
  glass = document.createElement("DIV");
  glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");
  /*insert magnifier glass:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
  /*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
  glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
  bw = 3;
  w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
  h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;
  /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
  glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  window.addEventListener("mousemove",outside);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  window.addEventListener("touchmove",outside);
  function outside() {
    glass.style.display = 'none';
  }
  function moveMagnifier(e) {
    glass.style.display = 'block';
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image*/
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    x = pos.x;
    y = pos.y;
    /*prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {x = img.width - (w / zoom);}
    if (x < w / zoom) {x = w / zoom;}
    if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {y = img.height - (h / zoom);}
    if (y < h / zoom) {y = h / zoom;}
    /*set the position of the magnifier glass:*/
    glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
    glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
    /*display what the magnifier glass "sees":*/
    glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}

function init() {
    magnify("export-a-product-to-china", 2);
}
/* Initiate Magnify Function with the id of the image, and the strength of the magnifier glass:*/
window.onload = init;// this is put in to ensure we don't try to get info about the img before it is loaded
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.img-magnifier-container {
  position:relative;
}
.img-magnifier-glass {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: none;
  /*Set the size of the magnifier glass:*/
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
</style>
<style>
.img-magnifier-container {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-magnifier-container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: none;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  animation-name: showgif;
  animation-duration: 33s;/* CHANGE THIS TO THE NUMBER OF SECONDS YOU WANT THE GIF TO SHOW */
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  z-index: -1;
}
@keyframes showgif {
  from {
    background-image: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a27e60318b27d7d0e86bd68/t/5fe7115448ad1f1396df7d5e/1608978804344/anipro_bw_finalgif.gif);
    z-index: 999999;
  }
  to {  
    background-image: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a27e60318b27d7d0e86bd68/t/5fe7115448ad1f1396df7d5e/1608978804344/anipro_bw_finalgif.gif);
    z-index: 999999;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img-magnifier-container">
  <img id="export-a-product-to-china" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a27e60318b27d7d0e86bd68/t/5fda32c7b424be58e1607b44/1608135367867/anipro_bw_final.svg" width="960" height="540">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes my bad! Thank you Mr. Haworth. The snippet is ok. 

The question is how I would be able to run a GIF and after it played, be replaced by the graphic (with the magnifying tool included).

Can you also tell me how to hide the magnifying glass after the cursor leaves the graphic?

Comment: Convert you gif into individual images or sprite then we can animate them and when that is complete we get rid of it and show the diagram and magnifier.

Comment: Or, if exact accuracy is not required, just time the GIF and we can set a timeout and fade it out and the diagram in when it's completed. Can you post a URL to the GIF? For the magnifying glass disappearing, you probably want to sense mouseout.

Comment: Certainly! Here is the link:https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a27e60318b27d7d0e86bd68/t/5fe7115448ad1f1396df7d5e/1608978804344/anipro_bw_finalgif.gif

The timeout option seems perfectly viable! The duration of the GIF is 33 sec.

Comment: Merry Christmas to you and all the friendly helpers out there. You make life beautiful.

Comment: Hello @AHaworth, I hope you're well. Would you have a look at what I added to my post in response to your comments? Thanks again in advance!